# how to deploy SharePoint WebPart?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sharepoint, deployment, windows-server-2008, web-parts

I am writing "HEllo World" WebPArt on Visual Studio 2008 installed on Windows Server 2008 Enterpise.
My Test SharePoint Webapplication  running on MIcrosoft EMEA Server. 
How can I deploy my WebPart into this WebApplication?

Comment: When you say "Microsoft EMEA Server" - do you mean it's hosted on Microsoft Business Productivity Online Services (BPOS, i.e. their current SharePoint cloud solution), on Office365 (their new cloud solution), or an internal server that your IT people control?

Comment: Yes it hosted on Microsoft EMEA Server!

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean with Microsoft EMEA server? Is it a hosted server or one you run yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio 2008, i'll assume that you are using SharePoint 2007 (either MOSS or WSS 3.0).

There are a number of ways you can deploy the web part. The simplest would probably be this one :

1. Download and install [WSPBuilder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/) (with the Visual Studio add-in)
2. Right-click and your project and choose "Build WSP"
3. Look in your folder for the *.wsp file which will contain your web part

Copy the wsp file on the server and open up a command line

Enter the following commands :

stsadm -o addsolution -filename {WSPFILENAME}
stsadm -o deploysolution -name {WSPFILENAME} -url {SITEURL}

There are simpler ways to do that (that don't involve the command line). Look at the documentation on the wspbuilder site.

There are also other add-ins for visual studio (including one built by Microsoft) that will help you with SharePoint solutions in Visual Studio 2008 but I have found WSPBuilder to be the most efficient way to build / deploy SharePoint solutions.

If you are using SharePoint 2010, then you really should upgrade to Visual Studio 2010, because all you have to do is F5 and it deploys your web part.

Comment: what you mean excatly with -url {SITEURL}??

Comment: Well, for example, if your site collection is on http://mysitecollection, then your command would end with "-url http://mysitecollection"

Answer (score 1):

From piecing together fragments from the 2 other almost idential questions you've asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096985/how-to-write-stsadm-deploysolution-correctly-sharepoint-webpart-deploying) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099041/load-sharepoint-2007-webpart-to-microsoft-online-emea) it appears that the **critical** bit of info you missed out of your question is that **your are using Microsoft's hosted BPOS aka SharePoint Online platform.**
(No one could work out what you meant by EMEA)

This isn't going to work for you. You have to install a web part actually on your farm by running STSADM actually **on your server**.

You can't do that as its a hosted server so you have to ask the hosting company (Microsoft in this case) to do this on your behalf.

If its the normal shared BPOS then you have no chance - they will not allow 3rd party or custom web parts.

- [Microsoft SharePoint Online Standard Developer Guide](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=d007f35e-375c-4b11-bc40-bc9082bb224a&displaylang=en) - What you can do to customise BPOS without using code.

If its BPOS-D (dedicated, 5000 seats+) then you can get them to deploy custom if you follow the 100 page process/guide here

- [SharePoint Online Dedicated Custom Solution Developers Guide_May 2011.docx](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=cf7d4db8-4e7c-4077-87ea-b64c57e4c98c)

Comment: +1 Great answer (and you're right, I didn't understand what he meant by EMEA)