# how to write stsadm -deploysolution correctly? sharepoint webpart deploying

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, web-parts

I got a help from other Question:

```
stsadm -o addsolution -filename {WSPFILENAME} stsadm -o deploysolution -name {WSPFILENAME} -url {SITEURL}
```

my WSP file is here:

```
C:\H\H\H.wsp
```

url:

```
https://test0emeamicrosoftonlinecom-6.sharepoint.emea.microsoftonline.com/
```

how to write this stsadm command correctly?

Comment: A better place to ask this would be http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Comment: WOW - You've asked pretty much the exact same question 3 times in a row, missing out the CRITICAL bit of info about being BPOS.

Comment: Duplicate and answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099041/load-sharepoint-2007-webpart-to-microsoft-online-emea

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will assume this is for SharePoint 2007.  There are two STSADM commands that need to be run (SharePoint 2010 should use Powershell...STSADM is only there for backwards compatibility).

[Add the solution](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263162%28office.12%29.aspx):

```
stsadm -o addsolution -filename C:\H\H\H.wsp
```

[Deploy the solution](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262459%28office.12%29.aspx):

The parameters for deploying your solution package are largely going to depend on what is in the solution and what needs to be deployed.

A simple global deployment may look something like this:

```
stsadm -o deploysolution -name H.wsp -immediate
```

For a deployment targeted to a specific web application in your farm and with assemblies being deployed to the GAC it may look something like this:

```
stsadm -o deploysolution -name H.wsp -url http://mydomain.com -allowgacdeployment -immediate
```